# add a NSArray to NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

i want to add a NSArray to my NSMutable ( init in the appdelegate )

this is my code, the method is call each time a button (male, female, couple) is pressed so an NSArray has to be add to the MutableArray but i don't know i tried stuff but doesnt work. :

```
     - (void) sexChoosen:(NSString *) sexe
{
    NSError *err;
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Boxes" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    NSArray *arrayForPredicate = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&err];
    NSPredicate *sex;

    sex = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"sexe = %@", sexe];

    NSArray  *BoxWithSex = [arrayForPredicate filteredArrayUsingPredicate:sex];
    //NSMutableArray* tmp = [self createMutableArray:BoxWithSex];

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSLog(@"FIRST  %@", appDelegate.myArray);

// HERE IS THE CODE TO ADD THE ARRAY TO MY NSMUTABLE ARRAY = AppDelegate *appDelegate

    NSLog(@"SECOND %@", appDelegate.myArray);

}
```

Comment: I don't see your mutable array.

Comment: Do you want to add the *objects from an array* to your mutable array, or add the array itself? Also, it's always a good idea to state your question *in question form*, including a question mark.

Answer (score 7):

From the NSMutableArray [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000138-BABDAJBD):

> "addObjectsFromArray: Adds the objects contained in another given array
>   to the end of the receiving array’s content."