# How do I append NSArray to NSMutableArray?

Tags: xcode, nsmutablearray

I am fetching several chunks of data coming in from a JSON API.

I want to append each of these answers to a final `NSMutableArray` but I can't      seem to get the syntax right.

I tried

```
[myMutableArray addObject: myPartialArray]
```

That doesn't work it says:

> addObject is not valid

What is the correct syntax so that I end up with one final array not containing the partial arrays? I really want it to be one large flat array, if that makes sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [add a NSArray to NSMutableArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585711/add-a-nsarray-to-nsmutablearray)

Comment: "it says: addObject is not valid"? Really? What "says" that? Is that verbatim? That would be very strange since a) the name of the method in your code snippet is `addObject:` with a colon and the compiler wouldn't leave that off; and b) that's a perfectly valid method to invoke on an `NSMutableArray`.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
[myMutableArray addObjectsFromArray: myPartialArray]
```

Also [described here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutablearray/1408963-addobjectsfromarray?changes=_6&language=objc)

Comment: This was the issue thanks will accept in 6 minutes when it lets me